# Как в C++ использовать код на Go?

Tags: c++, golang

Добрый день! Подскажите, как использовать функции из Go в программе на C++? Буду благодарен за простой и доступный пример.

Comment: Свежий go поддерживает создание dll/so (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573401/building-a-dll-with-go-1-7). А дальше там по накатанной.

Answer (score 4):

Файл hello.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "C"

//export Hello
func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}

func main() {}
```

Файл main.cpp:

```
#include "hello.h"

int main(void) {
    Hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Команды:

```
$ go build -buildmode c-archive hello.go
$ clang++ -lpthread -o main main.cpp hello.a
```

Результат:

```
$ ./main 
Hello, world!
```

Подробности [тут](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo) и [там](http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-sharing-libraries/).

Comment: А cgo поддерживает C++ с учетом новых стандартов или только подмножество включающее в себя часть C?

Comment: @GreenDragon cgo поддерживает только C, не C++.